# How to center the image element inside the wrapping div

Tags: html, css

[image: the way i would like to style my elements]

The ScreenShots of the jsx and css code and that of the web page is given below.

[image: image_jsx_css]

[image: webpage]

Comment: [Why you should use code examples instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1377002). [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the parent div a display flex and using the justify-content and align-items properties like this

```css
.movie_image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
}
```